Why the "log" in "log resolution"?
I have learned about log resolutions and log canonical thresholds. Recently, I wondered what the "log" in this terms means and where it comes from. I suspect, it is related to the usual logarithm but I don't know how. Also, I cannot find an explanation anywhere.
Thank you for your help!

I am by no means an expert, but I think it is the "log" from "log geometry". Here a Wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_structure

I think you get a better idea of the reason for the name from this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_form

Okay, I see. So, a log resolution makes the divisor locally normal crossing (by definition) and in this case the log forms are represented in a particularly easy way. And that is probably the way log resolutions came up first, and therefore the name.
Thank you!

Hi, as far I know the word Log is because we are adding terms of type $\frac{1}{f}$ to global forms $\omega_X$, and then the volume form is logarithmic.
